# Proof of "The sum of a convergent and divergent sequence is divergent"

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, solution-verification

I am simply wondering if my proof of this statement works.

Suppose $x_n$ converges to x and $y_n$ diverges.

Proof by contradiction.

Since $x_n$ converges, for any $ε$, there exists a natural number $N_x$ s.t. $n≥N_x$ implies $|x_n - x| < ε$. Now assume $x_n + y_n$ converges to $x + y$. Thus for an arbitrary $ε$, there exists a natural number $N_0$ s.t. $n≥N_0≥N_x$ implies $|(x_n + y_n) - (x+y)| < ε$. Since $y_n$ diverges, we know for any real number $y$, there exists $ε_y>0$ s.t. for any $N$, $n≥N$ and $|y_n - y| ≥ ε_y$. Thus,

$|(x_n + y_n) - (x+y)| ≥ ||x_n - x| - |y_n - y||$ (Reverse triangle inequality)

$||x_n - x| - |y_n - y|| ≥ ||x_n - x| - ε_y| ≥ 0$ ($y_n$ diverges)

Which then allows us to write $|x_n - x| ≥ ε_y$ for any $n≥N_0≥N_x$. Since $x_n$ converges, $|x_n - x|$ should be less than any arbitrary $ε$. Therefore, we have arrived at a contradiction. Hence $x_n + y_n$ diverges.

Comment: I am skeptical that you can really deduce that $|x_n-x|\geq \epsilon_y$.

Comment: In any case, a much easier argument is just that if $x_n+y_n$ converges, then so does $x_n+y_n-x_n = y_n$

Comment: "Since $y_n$ diverges, we know for any real number $y$, there exists $ε_y>0$ s.t. for any $N$, $n≥N$ and $|y_n - y| ≥ ε_y$." This sentence is incoherent/ambiguous. Please clarify.

Comment: @AdamRubinson If a sequence doesn't converge then it diverges. So I just negated the definition. I realize the n>=N is not needed because it is for all N.

Comment: @Andrew I can see why my proof is incorrect, but the most glaring issue (to me) is not what you pointed out. Do you mind explaining why we cannot deduce that?

Comment: @sla813 A definition of $(y_n)$ diverges could be:  For any real number $y$, there exists $\varepsilon_y>0$ s.t. for any $N$, there exists $n≥N$ s.t. $|y_n - y| ≥ ε_y$. This is not what you wrote though. [To me, what you wrote didn't make any sense].

Comment: @AdamRubinson Ok thank you. I see the issue. I made a mistake with the quantifiers.

Comment: "Which then allows us to write $|x_n - x| ≥ ε_y$" What is the justification for this statement?

Comment: @AdamRubinson I didn't think I made any errors in my reasoning before, so I thought I could add across the inequality in the preceding step.

Comment: I agree that the previous steps are fine, but I still don't see how you deduced from the previous steps that $|x_n - x| ≥ ε_y,$ which I think isn't necessarily true based on the previous steps. I do think you can say something like: $|x_n - x| ≥ \vert ε_y - \varepsilon\vert,$ but I don't see how you can say that $|x_n - x| ≥ ε_y.$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Suppose $x_n$ converges to $X$, $y_n$ diverges, and $x_n+y_n$ converges to $A$.  Then, we have

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}(x_n+y_n)=A$$

So, for any given $\varepsilon>0$, there is an $N$ such that whenever $n>N$,

$$A-x_n-\varepsilon<y_n<A-x_n+\varepsilon$$

And for this $\varepsilon$, let's take $n$ so large that $X-\varepsilon<x_n<X+\varepsilon$.

Then, we see that for sufficiently large $n$

$$A-X-2\varepsilon<y_n<A-X+2\varepsilon$$

But this implies that $y_n$ converges to $A-X$.

The contradiction proves that $x_n+y_n$ cannot converge.  And we are done!

Answer (score 4):

Assume that $(x_n)$ converges. Let $z_n = x_n + y_n$ and assume that $(z_n)$ converges. Then the difference sequence $(w_n)$ with $w_m = z_n - x_n$ converges. But $w_n = y_n$, thus $(y_n)$ converges.  This excludes that the sum of a convergent and divergent sequence is convergent.